# Is it possible to have an IRC client using websockets running your own IRC server without a websockets gateway?

Tags: node.js, sockets, meteor, websocket, irc

I am planning build an IRC network and been exploring options. I am planning to use [Inspircd IRC Server](http://www.inspircd.org/). Along with a webserver running [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). Is it possible to build a web IRC client with websockets and NOT using a webscokets gateway (to reduce load on webserver) and directly connect to the IRC Inspircd box?

Secondly, If Yes to above, what are the pros/cons of having `IRCclient <-> IRCServer` vs  `IRCclient <-> WebScoketGateway (/webserver) <-> IRC Server` relationship.

I see most of the modules involving node or meteor (including [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) use a WSGI, why is that? Am I missing something here?

Please note in this case, both IRC Server and Webserver are run by me and hence the possibility of making the browser believe both are same boxes.

Comment: You can set up flash sockets to communicate with a compatible IRC server as flash isn't domain restricted, see https://github.com/atheme/iris/pull/41 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to build a web IRC client with websockets and NOT using a webscokets gateway (to reduce load on webserver) and directly connect to the IRC Inspircd box?

No. WebSockets are a layer inside HTTP, i.e. the client sends a HTTP request with an Upgrade header and the server responds with a HTTP response acknowledging the Upgrade request. The data is exchanged as binary messages (with their own framing) and also usually xor'ed with some key.

Thus you cannot send arbitrary and also not IRC data to a non-WebSocket server but you need a gateway to translate from the WebSocket handshake and frames to normal TCP.

Comment: So this means that there should be a WebSocket Gateway in between. Would it not add a lot of overhead? And as for security, I own both the webserver and the irc box, so that should be someway to overcome the overhead on the webserver with some kind of crossdomain access?

Comment: @user537051: If you use WebSockets instead of plain sockets then you will have the overhead because of how WebSockets work. And even if you would do it cross-domain you still would have the same overhead, only at another place.

Answer (score 1):

UnrealIRCd 4.0.10 and later [support the WebSocket protocol](https://www.unrealircd.org/docs/WebSocket_support) (ws:// and wss://). WebSocket frames exchange the same messages as on standard IRC connection.